# Using Ruby server as API middleman

Tags: ruby, api, server

I am trying to call an API from my ruby server and simply pass the response back to my client. 
How do I make sure the response is passed back to the client. I am currently getting back an empty response with a status code of 204

```
class SignupPlayerPagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize

  def index
    render locals: { signup_player_pages: SignupPlayerPage.all }
  end

  def show
    signup_player_page = SignupPlayerPage.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
    return render json: { error: 'Not found' }, status: :not_found if signup_player_page.nil?

    render locals: { signup_player_page: signup_player_page }
  end

  def sms
    response = HTTParty.get('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow')
    return response
  end
end
```

The current HTTParty request is a dummy request I just want to know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

which method is returning empty? index, show or sms?

if its sms, the you may need to do something like:

```
render json: { message: response }
```

instead of the "return response". Btw the "return response" can be deleted anyway, its redundant.